# Java generics in an interface

Tags: java, generics, interface

I have run into a problem with generics in Java and I can't find a solution or example online of someone using generics in a similar fashion. I have a set of methods that are in the same request/response structure. For example, a user populates fields in the Request object, passes the object to a helper method, and they are returned a Response object. All of my request objects extend from a common Request super class (and similarly, Response objects from a Response super class). I would like my helper classes to also have a consistent structure so I have used an interface. Here is some code to illustrate...

Request super class:

```
public class SuperRequest {
    // ...
}
```

Example Request subclass:

```
public class SubRequest extends SuperRequest {
    // ...
}
```

Response super class:

```
public class SuperResponse {
    // ...
}
```

Example response subclass:

```
public class SubResponse extends SuperResponse{
    // ...
}
```

The interface:

```
public interface SomeInterface {
    public <T extends SuperRequest, U extends SuperResponse> U someMethod(T request);
}
```

As you can see from the interface, I want to pass an object that is a child of `SuperRequest` and I want to return an object that is a child of `SuperResponse`. Here is my implementation:

```
public class SomeImplementation implements SomeInterface {

    @Override
    public SubResponse someMethod(SubRequest request) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

In Eclipse, I get compilation errors because the compiler tells me I have unimplemented methods and the `@Override` notation "does not override a supertype method".

Can anyone help me here? Is my syntax incorrect or is my understanding of generics a little off? Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try changing your interface and implementation to:

```
interface SomeInterface<T extends SuperRequest, U extends SuperResponse> {
    public U someMethod(T request);
}

class SomeImplementation implements SomeInterface<SubRequest, SubResponse> {

    @Override
    public SubResponse someMethod(SubRequest request) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Awesome! I had a feeling I was just a bit off on the syntax/declaration. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

As it stands, the implementation of `SomeInterface` must implement the parameterized method, i.e.:

```
public <T extends SuperRequest, U extends SuperResponse> U someMethod(T request);
```

It can't choose a particular Subclass to substitute for `T` and `U`.

The interface itself must be generic `SomeInterface<T extends SuperRequest, U extends SuperResponse>` and the subclass can then choose concrete implementations for `T` and `U`.

Answer (score 1):

You have to declare the types as well when you implement the interface. Try this:

```
public class SomeImplementation implements SomeInterface<SubRequest,SubResponse> {

    @Override
    public SubResponse someMethod(SubRequest request) {
        return null;
    }
}
```